# arduino serial monitor not opening

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I have been working with my arduino Uno on Ubuntu Linux (It won't work on Windows with my laptop). For a few days it worked fine, but recently I have been working with the Serial Port. It was all good, until the Serial Monitor stopped opening. It would have a process open, and using alt+tab it would show the window for it, but I couldn't get it to show normally or be interacted with in any way. I have opened it going tools>Serial Monitor, ctrl+shift+m, and the button for it. I can upload fine. I can't find the dynamic IP address for the arduino, or for just fun remotely interacting with it.

Answer (score 0):

open the terminal and tap the following commands:

```
sudo usermod -a -G dialout xxxxx
sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyACM0
```

NOTE: xxxxx is your username